# Find-replace: find from file and replace using key:value relation

Tags: replace, find

I have a file (a) like the follow:

> ('gi|290490588':0.0,'gi|290490602':0.00137,('gi|566163369':0.638271,('gi|302765619':0    .804737,(('gi|1026768672':0.692344,'gi|167999440':0.559082)[&label=1.0]:0.768415,(((((('gi|922359590':0.0,'gi|92    2359592':0.01216)[&label=1.0]:0.644957,(('gi|1026759849':0.279671,'gi|302813174':0.27607)[&label=0.969]:0.159941    ,('gi|168027479':0.522018,('gi|168039221':0.045808,('gi|168041596':0.077145, ...

I have to replace the gene ids (e.g. gi|290490588) with a more informative label. I have another file (b) with the ids-label correspondence.

key -------------|--value

gi|290490588 |  foo

gi|290490602 | bar

I want to search file "a" with file "b" first column (key) and replace the ids in file "a" with the second column of file "b" (value).